# jquery full month calendar able to put controls in month

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Is there a JQuery plugin that allows to display a full month? like in outlook for example, but I need to put inside each day some checkboxes and labels, in other words, custom html inside each day.

Any help will be appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

(I've not used this personally, but saw another question related to this previously here today.)

Comment: interesting, but seems mostly for events, do you know if i can put custom html inside each month, like a textbox or checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

I this should work for you:

http://www.bytecyclist.com/projects/jmonthcalendar/

I don't see support, out-of-the-box, but you can definitely add html components using jQuery. For example, a table cell uses the following markup:

```
<td id="c_11272011" class="DateBox Weekend Inactive" date="11/27/2011">
```

You could add a component programatically like so:

```
$('td[date="11/27/2011"]').append('<input type="text"/>');
```

Hope that helps!